# Connect-VIServer will always propt a dialog to enter username & password

Tags: windows, powershell, powercli

I rung the following command inside powercli 5.5:-

```
PowerCLI C:\> Connect-VIServer -Server  172.16.20.101 -User root -Password ****
```

but I got a dialog to enter username and password although I am supplying the username & password in the script `-User` & `-Password`? so can anyone advice why powercli is not recognizing  these parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `User` and `Password` parameters have been deprecated in the newest versions of PowerCLI. Use `-Credential` with a `pscredential` object instead:

```
$Username = 'root'
$Password = 'Sup4hS3cuRe' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password

Connect-VIServer -Server 172.16.20.101 -Credential $Credential
```

Comment: not sure how did it work but I just surrounded the password with " " and I can connect without being prompted with a dialog ...

Comment: @JohnJohn Cool, if that's your solution, add an answer yourself :)

Comment: I think your script is better and more secure, but when I run your script I got the following error :- New-Object : Cannot find type [pscredential]: make sure the assembly containing
 this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:25
+ $Credential = New-Object <<<<  -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList $Username
,$Password
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewOb
   jectCommand

Comment: @Mathiase I am using power shell 5.5 release 1. can you advice on this please?

Comment: @JohnJohn try substituting `pscredential` with the full type name `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential`